# Conditional binding in ASCX page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom list object and I am binding it to a repeater like this

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
<p>Opsigelsesdato:<input type="text" value="<%Eval("EndDate.month")+ "/01/"+ Eval("EndDate.year")%>" /></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now what I want is I want to bind values to this input only if `EndDate.month` is not equal to null. IS there any way to do this in ASCX page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do something like this:**

**Create a public method on the page then call that from the code-in-front.**

e.g. if using C#:

```
public string ProcessMyDataItem(object myValue)
{
  if (myValue == null)
  {
     return "0";
  }

  return myValue.ToString();
}
```